# Can someone please tell me why hitting the back button in my app always takes me back to the home screen?

Tags: android

I've read through and tried several of the suggested solutions and nothing seems to work. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here is some additional information. My Application can go as deep as 4 activities. For example, after launching from the home screen, the user is taken to my applications main menu. From here they can click an options menu to view an about screen that gives them version info etc. My assumption would be if they hit back from the about menu that they would be taken back to my applications main menu. Instead, the app exits and they are taken back to the home screen. Logcat gives the following output:

D/MAIN_BROWSER: MainBrowser::onCreate
D/MAIN_BROWSER: MainBrowser::onStart
D/MAIN_BROWSER: MainBrowser::onResume

** the above is as expected. Now I hit the about activity **

D/MAIN_BROWSER: MainBrowser::onSaveInstanceState
D/MAIN_BROWSER: MainBrowser::onPause
D/ABOUT: AboutBroswer::onCreate
D/ABOUT: AboutBrowser::onStart
D/ABOUT: AboutBrowser::onResume

** now user hits the back button **

D/ABOUT: AboutBrowser::onBackPressed
D/ABOUT: AboutBrowser::onPause
D/MAIN_BROWSER: MainBrowser::onStop
D/MAIN_BROWSER: MainBrowser::onDestroy

** now I'm back at the home screen **

Thanks,
BRoid

Comment: Could you please describe the problem in greater detail...
Did you start your app from the home screen?
Does your app have multiple activities?
Is the problem that pressing back seems to skip past earlier activities in the stack?

Comment: this is a very poor way to ask a question on this site.  you must include much more detail on your problem and supply some code!!

Comment: You have to have a "problem" before you can try "solutions". You should first tell us what the "problem" you're having is.

Answer (score 1):

If your app only has one activity, or if you have called `finish()` for all but the current activity in your app, then that's what the back button will do.

Comment: My app can go as deep as 4 activities. The problem I'm having, for example, is when launched from the home screen the user is taken to my apps main menu. Here they can click on a menu option to view an "About" screen. In the About screen, if the user hits back, I would expect them to be taken back to my apps main menu. Instead, my app is completely exited and the user taken back to the home screen.

Comment: @BuckeyeDroid Ever find a solution? I have having the same problem!